# Svelte derived store

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

yo!

im trying to update my derived store, i do the following

```
// store.js line: 20
    const updateProductOrder = newOrder => {
        update(builderStore => {
            console.log(builderStore) //undefined
        })
    }
```

function is triggered by drag'n'drop product card on, line 35 Products.svelte
it works great in all other functions that are executed in main component using same logic, for some reason it doesnt work in nested component like in example:
https://svelte.dev/repl/5287e7b0ba994772ae736fcc41952b08?version=3

can you please help why it doesnt work?

Comment: Can you update the questions title please! Seeing this title in search results is not helpful for anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A store update function must return the new value. What you want is probably

```js
const updateProductOrder = newOrder => {
    update(builderStore => {
        console.log(builderStore)
        return newOrder
    })
}
```

The [svelte docs for writable store](https://svelte.dev/docs#writable) show the update contract as roughly.

```js
    store.update((oldValue) => { return newValue })
```

In your example, you lack a return statement, so you end up returning `undefined` and thus setting your store's new value to `undefined`.

Here is an [updated repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/a342042f7bdf4e2a8fd25ada0f35f0de?version=3.29.7) with just this change added. You can also look in the [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores) for a small example in the `Incrementer.svelte` tab.